# windows resize active and disable slider on different widths

Tags: javascript, jquery, unslider

code:

```
$(function() {
     var win = $(window);

     resizeHandler();

     win.resize(resizeHandler);
     var fired = false;

     function resizeHandler() {
     if (win.width() <= 991 && !fired) {
     $('.element').unslider();
        fired = true;
     } else if (win.width() >= 992) {
        slider.unslider('destroy');
     }
   }
});
```

So I want the slider to work when it's below 991px and stop working when above. All when resizing but right now on refresh when higher than 991 slider wont appear ever and when refreshing below 991 slider wont disappear when going over 991px?

Would be nice that have some input or recommened me a slider library in where you can disable certain width?

thanks in advance.

Comment: You want the slider to remain there but stop sliding or you want to remove it completely ?

Comment: You can use CSS with media queries to hide the slider for certain resolutions, this way the slider will remain instantiated.

Comment: remove completely, but not the elements, I need it to be like before without adding unslider.

Comment: Are you sure about `slider.unslider('destroy');`, I don't find any method or option [here](http://unslider.com/). Maybe `slider.unslider('stop');` will help

Comment: in the elseif slider is undefined.

Comment: try $('.element').remove();  this will completely remove the slider element.

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution: Just remove classes used my unslider (like "unslider-wrap unslider-carousel"). Following code has been tested with unslider demo

```
$(function() {
     var win = $(window),
         mySlider = $(".my-slider");

     resizeHandler();

     win.resize(resizeHandler);

   function resizeHandler() {
     if (win.width() <= 991) {
        mySlider .addClass ("unslider-wrap unslider-carousel");
     } else if (win.width() >= 992) {
        mySlider.removeClass ("unslider-wrap unslider-carousel");
     }
   }
});

<div class="default-slider unslider-horizontal">
    <ul class="my-slider unslider-wrap unslider-carousel">
        <li>Slide 1</li>
        <li class="unslider-active">Slide 2</li>
        <li class="">Slide 3</li>
        <li class="">Slide 4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```